# Maintain sessions in WPF applications

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, session

I am implementing a POS system. I am hoping to have a log-in capability built in to the system. standalone WPF applications are running in different POSs and they are connected to a central database.

What is the best way of achieving the Log-in functionality in this scenario?

**PS**: When the sales person logged in, if the POS is idling for 15 mins, it has to be automatically logged-in.

**Edit**: Basically what I tough was, since this same WPF application (Interface to the sales person) is going to be installed in several machines, and any sales person can access the application using any of these machines. In websites, we are using sessions and cookies, but what should be my approach because this is stand alone WPF application which only access the database. Obviously password can be kept in database is a secured manner. I can keep a thread to wait for 15 mins and popup a log-in window which freezes the working window.

Comment: What have you come up with so far? and what part you would like to discuss?

Comment: @AdilMughal I have included some more details, can you help me on this.

Comment: The best approach for what? A POS system? Remote log-in? Connecting to a central database? Sessions? Cookies? The two are different. You have to ask a single, answerable, question. Have you built a WPF application before?

Comment: @DourHighArch No I havent, OH, now it got why I got -3 :(, look to the edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 15 mins check, you can use [DispatchTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx) which you need to start on idle and reset when salesperson start using it.

Rest of the login system is simple username and password verification using stored encrypted/hashed password in database... however you can also utilize asp.net membership APIs with your desktop application. See [ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163807.aspx)

Comment: ok thanks a lot, I will work on this and see.

Comment: I think I can not use membership APIs with the desktop applications. Correct me if I am wrong. I used Dispatcher Timer to get the job done. Thank you